# Delegates issues

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates

I can't get why I can't set delegate. I'm using UINavigationController to switch between two views. Here is my code

SecondViewProtocol.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol SecondViewProtocol <NSObject>
    @required
    -(void)textFieldDidChange:(NSString *)data;
@end
```

SecondView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SecondViewProtocol.h"
@interface SecondView : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) id<SecondViewProtocol>delegate;
@end
```

SecondView.m

```
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
.......

-(IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender
{
    [[self delegate] textFieldDidChange:[self.textField text]];
}

.......
```

I have imported SecondViewProtocol.h in FirstView.h

FirstView.m

```
....
SecondView *secondView = [[SecondView alloc]init];
secondView.delegate = self;
....
```

Here I get Assigning to id  from incompatible type FirtView.

What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, delegate property should be declared as `assign`, not `retain`. You should never retain delegates.
Second, `FirstView` should conform to `SecondViewProtocol` like the following.

```
@interface FirstView: UIViewController <SecondViewProtocol>
```